# How to create MTA in NEO environment

Tags: cloud-foundry, sap-cloud-platform

I need to create a MTA archive from existing html5 application in NEO development account. Need to create MTA and deploy it in the provider account. I'm struggling to create the MTA in NEO environment. It gives below error for me.

Technical error [Invalid MTA archive [MTAShop_0.0.1.mtar]. MTA deployment descriptor (META-INF/mtad.yaml) could not be parsed. For more information, see the troubleshooting section of the official documentation in the SAP Help Portal about resolving descriptor errors. Technical details: Unsupported module type "javascript.nodejs" for platform type "HCP-CLASSIC"]

mta.yaml:

```
ID: MTAShop
_schema-version: '2.0'
version: 0.0.1
modules:
  - name: sample.Shop
    type: html5
    path: sample.Shop
    parameters:
      disk-quota: 128M
      memory: 128M
    build-parameters:
      builder: grunt
```

Answer (score 1):

for NEO, according to https://help.sap.com/viewer/58746c584026430a890170ac4d87d03b/Cloud/en-US/ba7dd5a47b7a4858a652d15f9673c28d.html the HTML5 type is com.sap.hcp.html5

So just replace "type: html5" to "type: com.sap.hcp.html5" and should work.